# Simple Monte Carlo integration about b-a

Tags: statistics, computational-mathematics, monte-carlo

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why we need to * (b-a). Here b-a = 4-2=2.I think we already make random x from 2 to 4. We've already considered the interval (not 0,1). Why do we times (b-a) again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are approaching this integration by approximating the average value of $e^{-x}$ over $[2,4]$ (I.e., the average y value) and multiplying it by the length of the x interval to get the estimate of the integral.

More precisely:

$$ \bar{f}_{[a,b]}= \frac{\int_a^b f dx}{b-a}$$

The code `mean(exp(-x))` is estimating $\bar{f}_{[a,b]}$ so you need to multiply by the “base” of the rectangle you are making.

Comment: Nicely direct and to the point (+1)

Comment: I didn't find this formula in my Rudin analysis book. What's the name?

Comment: @christine https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/avgfcnvalue.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe comparing Monte Carlo integration with Riemann approximation
will help you understand the former.

Suppose we want to approximate the integral $J = \int_a^b e^{-x}\,dx$
by $n=1000$ rectangles of widths $w$ and heights $h = e^{-m},$ where $m$ is the midpoint of the base of a rectangle. In R,

```
a = 2;  b = 4
n = 1000
w = (b-a)/n
m = seq(a+w/2, b-w/2, length=n)
h = exp(-m)
sum(w*h)
[1] 0.1170196
```

This is a deterministic computation, so each run will give the same answer.

You are integrating the density function of the distribution $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate\,}=\lambda = 1).$ In R, the CDF of
this distribution is `pexp` (with default $\lambda=1).$ So a Riemann approximation with 1000 evenly spaced grid points as centers of rectangles has given us four-place accuracy.

```
diff(pexp(c(2,4)))
[1] 0.1170196
```

A basic Monte Carlo integration substitutes for the evenly spaced points above, randomly chosen $m$ distributed as $\mathsf{Unif}(a,b).$
For this one-dimensional integration, randomly chosen grid
points are not quite as efficient as a precisely evenly spaced
grid.  So I will use $n = 10\,000$ random points (uniformly distributed).

```
set.seed(2021)
a = 2;  b = 4
n = 10000
w = (b-a)/n
m = runif(m, a, b)
h = exp(-m)
sum(w*h)
[1] 0.01189166
```

This is a random procedure, so (for different seeds, or no set seed)
the result will be slightly different on each run.

The *average* widths are $w = (b-a)/n.$ If I had used `mean` instead of
`sum` as you did, that would take care of the $1/n,$ but the
length of the interval, over which the integration takes place, is still needed.

---

*Note: Sampling method.* For Monte Carlo integration in one dimension, a 'sampling
method' is sometimes used (often more for its ease of programming than for its efficiently). If we use the R function `rexp` to sample a million observations from $\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda=1),$ then we can ask what proportion of them
lie between $2$ and $4.$

```
set.seed(120)
x = rexp(10^6)
mean((x>2)&(x<4))
[1] 0.117494
```

The vector `(x>2)&(x<4)` is a logical vector with a million
elements `TRUE` or `FALSE`; the mean of a logical vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s.

This method is especially convenient when it would be
some trouble to find the density function of the distribution of interest. Suppose time to completion of a 2-phase process is the sum of $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=30,\sigma = 5)$ and $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda = .05).$ The the waiting time to completion is $W = Z+X.$ The average waiting time $E(W) = E(Z)+E(X) = 30+20 = 50,$ and $P(W > 60) \approx 0.22935 \pm 0.00084.$

```
set.seed(109)
z = rnorm(10^6, 30,5)
x = rexp(10^6, .05)
w = z + x
mean(w > 60)
[1] 0.229349
2*sd(w > 60)/1000
[1] 0.0008408287


hist(w, prob=T, br=60, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Time to Completion")
 abline(v = 60, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

*Note: Higher dimensions.* The accuracy of a basic Monte Carlo integration
depends in part on the "wiggliness" of the function $f(x)$
being  integrated. However, generally speaking, Monte Carlo integrations in two (or higher) dimensions with $n$ randomly chosen points are about as good as (or better than) a Riemann approximation with a grid of $n$ evenly spaced points.

Example: The integral of a bivariate standard normal
distribution (correlation $0)$ over first quadrant of the unit circle can be shown to be $J = 0.0984.$

```
pchisq(1,2)/4
[1] 0.09836734
```

We show Monte Carlo integration
with about $100^2\pi/4$ points randomly distributed in the
triangle. Notice we average the random heights and multiply
by the area of the quarter circle.

```
set.seed(1234)  # 1234
n = 100;  u1 = runif(n);  u2 = runif(n)
h.sq = dnorm(u1)*dnorm(u2)
h.qd = h.sq[u1^2 + u2^2 < 1]
(pi/4)*mean(h.qd)
[1] 0.09813584
```